# UIImageView memory Leak

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

In my app, I am loading series of images to my `UIImageView` which has been created on `init` Method like

```
- (UIImage *)getImage:(int)currentIndex {
    NSString *path = [self getImagePath:currentIndex];
    [self.imageView setAccessibilityLabel:path]; 

    path=[bundle pathForResource:path ofType:extension];    
    return  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path] ;

}

- (void)changeImage:(int)currentIndex {

    [self.imageView setImage:nil ];
    [self.imageView setImage:[self getImage:currentIndex]];

}
```

But this code causes memory leaks .Something like

**-malloc - 7KB - imageIO - png_malloc**

i have tried "[[UIImage alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile]" with appropriate release calls but still no luck.

What am i missing on here.

Roughly whole class

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andBundle:(NSBundle *) bundleTobeInjected {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    self.opaque = YES;
        bundle=bundleTobeInjected;
        commonFunctions=[[Common alloc] init];
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] ;
        [self.imageView setImage:nil ];
        self.imageView.contentMode = self.contentMode;
        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [self setAccessibilityEnabled];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setAccessibilityEnabled
{
    self.imageView.isAccessibilityElement=true;
}

#pragma mark - Custom Logic
- (NSString *)getImagePath:(int)currentIndex {

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", prefix,currentIndex,[commonFunctions imageNamedSmartForRotationSuffix]];
    NSLog(@"%@", path);
    return path;
}

- (UIImage *)getImage:(int)currentIndex {
    NSString *path = [self getImagePath:currentIndex];
    [self.imageView setAccessibilityLabel:path]; 

    path=[bundle pathForResource:path ofType:extension];    
    return  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path] ;

}

-(void)changeImage:(int)currentIndex {


    [self.imageView setImage:nil ];
    [self.imageView setImage:[self getImage:currentIndex]];


}


-(void)dealloc{
    [extension release];
    [prefix release];
    [defaultImage release];
    [image release];
    [imageView release];
    [commonFunctions release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Just enable ARC. It solves all memory management for you. That was easy.

Comment: i will create a branch and try with ARC. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'll bet if you ran the analyzer it would point you right at the bug.

Comment: @HotLicks It would have immediately shown it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code doesn't leak. Your leak is somewhere else :)

The leak is in the `init` method. Look at this line :

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

That line creates an image view *that you own* because you used an `init` method. You then assign that to your property *which owns it again* because I'm guessing your property is `retain`. You need to release the imageView after you've assigned it to your property, like this :

```
self.imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
```

---

PS You don't need this line

```
[self.imageView setImage:nil ];
```

Comment: When i profile with simulator , it doesnt show me a leak but on device it does.

when i  get "UiImage* tempImage=[self getImage:currentIndex]" but doesnt set it to imagevew, it does not show a memory leak. Maybe you are right, a bug in Profiler

Comment: Don't test for leaks on the Simulator - it uses a different memory model so you won't get the right results. Always trust the device. But, still, the code in your question doesn't have any leaks - your leak is something else that is keeping your `UIImage` hanging around. Probably the `UIImageView` that I don't think you are releasing in your `dealloc`.

Comment: Ok. Good point for Simulator.

I am releasing UIImageView on dealloc. Thanks for checking. 

I updated y question with code of whole class


Here is the screenshot of Profiler

http://i46.tinypic.com/vq4d3p.png

Comment: retain was not causing memory leak . leak was coming from a ios library but even though instrument was showing a memory leak, it wasn't causing an issue (app has been approved by Apple) . 

From now on i will be switching to ARC  anyway.

thanks for help guys and sorry for late response.